# Enable jquery panzoom on some event

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery.panzoom

I'm using a jquery plugin that allows zooming and pan functionality, however I want this to be done only at some event( say when checkbox is clicked) because after having it by all the time, the default functionalities are getting affected which are through another plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done something like this,

```
$("#ID").panzoom("disable"); - To disable panzoom for this element

$("#ID").panzoom("enable"); - To enable panzoom for this element
```